# Pushing to an path in ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, immutable.js

```
  setprocesses = setprocessType.setIn([processTypeId, 'processes'], List(List.of(process)))
        processTypeGroups = setprocesses
```

I'm trying to push an object into the path I've set straight on the object, named `processes`. On the object, I want to push a `process` into the path while I set the key. Using `.push` path the end will throw. I dunno how this would turn out if I use something like `object.setIn([...], () => something)`. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating an object that pushed the value through getIn. Furthermore you can later use SetIn to declare what you would mount on that path, in this case an List of Maps. Here's how this gets transformed.

```
 setprocesses = setprocessType.setIn([processTypeId, 'processes'], List([]))
        pushToMap = setprocesses.getIn([processTypeId, 'processes']).push(process)
        processTypeGroups = setprocesses.setIn([processTypeId, 'processes'], pushToMap)
```